# sandbox :get NSData using bookmarkDataWithOptions method of NSURL without NSOpenPanel

Tags: cocoa, sandbox

I enabled sandbox and I want to create data by bookmarkDataWithOptions.
If the URL is created by NSPanel that work very well. But, If I obtain URL without using NSOpenPanel, the bookmarkDataWithOptions method always return nil. why?

thank about If I want to set a special folder default can read/write without using NSOpenPanel.
How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: What is the path of this special folder? If it's outside the sandbox, you will not be able to create a SSB.

Answer (score 1):

The main feature of the Sandbox is security. If an application could read/write an arbitrary folder without user permission, the security would be broken.

The [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html) states clearly:

> • Simulation of user input in Open and Save dialogs:
>   if your app depends on programmatically manipulating Open or Save dialogs to simulate or alter user input, your app is unsuitable for sandboxing.

The only way to achieve something similar, is to add a read/write entitlement to one of the preset directories (Documents, Pictures, Music, etc…). For further documentation, take a look at this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1).